# How to validate an auto complete string field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, forms, validation, autocomplete

I have a web-app with an location text field that has an auto complete that pulls data from Google Maps to complete the location typed in. What I want to to is force the user to choose the specific spelling and format that the auto complete gives for the location that is being typed i.o.w. a validation. The user thus can't type anything random in the location field.

I have:

```
validates :location, :presence => true
```

,but that doesn't really help. Is there a custom validation? Or one I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `before_validation` thing like the following

```
before_validation do
  self.location = YourClassName.find_by_location_name(location)
end
```

It's just an idea to get that worked. It's not an exact answer you needed.

Comment: I also thought of using a before_validation, but integrating the auto complete not so clear on ;)